# Trying to bold y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to bold my y-axis. The title for the axis is bold, but I can't seem to figure out how to bold the number themselves. Here is my code so far,

```
combine.df %>% filter(site== "indian_creek") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = percent_corn, y = flow_concentration)) +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", color="black") +
geom_point(color=dark_umber, size=5) + 
scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10, bold) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(46, 58, by=2)) +
theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1)) +labs(title = "Indian Creek", 
face="bold", x = "Cultivated Crop as Corn (%)",
y = expression(bold(Weighted~Flow~NO[3]-N~(kg/m^{3}))))  +
theme(
# LABLES APPEARANCE
plot.title = element_text(size=14, face= "bold", colour= "black" ),
axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),    
axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),    
axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold", colour = "black"), 
axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold", colour = "black"),
strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face="bold", colour = "black"),
axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.3)
)
```

I have seen similar questions but haven't figured out the right answer for my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Looks like they are bold. Maybe hard to see with your font or with everything bolded already?

```
mtcars %>%   # Replaced with reproducible data
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color="black") +
  geom_point(color="brown", size=5) + 
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 58, by=2)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1)) +
  labs(title = "Indian Creek",face="bold", x = "Cultivated Crop as Corn (%)",
       y = expression(bold(Weighted~Flow~NO[3]-N~(kg/m^{3})))) +
  theme(
    # LABELS APPEARANCE
    plot.title = element_text(size=14, face= "bold", colour= "black" ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),    
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),    
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold", colour = "black"), 
    # axis.text.y = element_text(size=12,  colour = "black"), # unbold
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold", colour = "black"), # bold
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face="bold", colour = "black"),
    axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.3)
  )
```

[image: bold version]

[image: unbold version]