# Bolded axis with subscripted character using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bold axis label with a subscripted character using ggplot2 in R.

I have already tried the following, but the subscripted number seems to be 'unbolded' (see image below).

[image: Current results]

It appears that the 2 after 'log' on the y-axis is not in bold. However, the answer posted here ([Trying to bold y axis in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884194/trying-to-bold-y-axis-in-ggplot)) seems to suggest that it is. Is this just the way `ggplot2` makes it look?

Here is a bit of code to replicate the problem (if it is indeed a problem) using a simpler data set and less formatting of the plot output (which shouldn't make a difference to the axis labels):

```
library(ggplot2)  

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(bold('Coefficient estimate for log'[2]*' FPRS variable'))) + 
  xlab(expression(bold('This is what a normal 2 looks like')))
```

I have also tried the following (which gives the same result):

```
labs(y = expression(bold('Coefficient estimate for log'[2]*' FPRS variable')))
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `latex2exp` you can bold text easily with wrapping the text with `'\\textbf{}'` and use LaTeX for `Log_2`

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(latex2exp)

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(TeX('\\textbf{Coefficient estimate for $log_2$ FPRS variable}')) + 
  xlab(TeX('\\textbf{This is what a normal 2 looks like}'))
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer has worked for me in the past, but for reasons that I may never fully understand, it doesn't always work. In these instances, I had to use something like the following:

```
ylab(expression(bold("Coefficient estimate for log"["2"]*" FPRS variable")))
```

Note the quotations around the subscripted `2`. This comes from [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902671/how-can-i-use-bold-and-expression-in-ggplot-with-special-characters) on this wonderful website.