# How can I use bold and expression in ggplot with special characters?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, special-characters

I think that is very simple.

I'm using bold in the expression function in ggplot2.
It's all clear for me and it works.
But when I use it with special characters like `mu*mol` to have `μmol` or `H[2]*O` to have `2` as subscript, it doesn't work.
Practically it doesn't make bold the special characters.

I tried to use the bold function that I know with expression in ggplot.

I show you only the string of the plot code that I use to set label.

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ ./5, name = expression(bold(atop(H[2]*O,(mu*mol~m^bold("-2")~s^bold("-1"))))),breaks=c(-3,-1.5,0,1.5,3)),breaks=seq(-10,20,10))
```

In the figure you can see that `μ` is not bold and the subscript `2` of `H2O` is not bold.
[image]

Comment: have you tried quoting the 2? `H["2"]`

Comment: No.
I don't know this function.
How does it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's enough to use a single `bold` statement in your expression, but then you have to surround every subscript and superscript with quotation marks. This would still leave your greek letter `mu` without bold face, b/c `plotmath` doesn't have bold symbol fonts (see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/232923.html)). However, you can circumvent this by replacing `mu` with the unicode character (you can find them [here](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~raymond/software/howtos/greekscape.xhtml)).

Here I've just used the standard `mtcars` data set.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = qsec)) +
geom_line() +
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ ./5, 
                                       name = expression(bold(atop(H["2"]*O,("\u03bc"*mol~m^"-2"~s^"-1"))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Great @Arienrhod!
I didn't know this list of codes.

Thank you!
You resolved my question, easly!